# Preview and remove an image before uploading with jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In one of my forms I have an input field for image uploads in Wordpress. Also I have a jQuery script that preview the selected image before upload and add a Remove link for this preview. This works very well if they are in one file (a plugin), but the Remove link doesn't work if the jQuery script is enqueued in a separate JS file, it just sends to the top of the page. Why this happens?

I tried to add an `event.preventDefault();` as below, but this doesn't helped:

```
jQuery('#image_preview a').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
```

The CSS/HTML part:

```
<style>
#image_preview {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="image"/>

<div id="image_preview">
    <img src="#" id="image-preview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" /><br />
    <a id="image_remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery part:

```
/** 
  onchange event handler for the file input field.
* It emplements very basic validation using the file extension.
* If the filename passes validation it will show the image 
   using it's blob URL and will hide the input field and show a delete
   button to allow the user to remove the image.
*/
//jQuery('#image').on('change', function () {
jQuery( document ).delegate('#image', 'change', function() {
    ext = jQuery(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if (jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
        resetFormElement(jQuery(this));
        window.alert('Not an image!');
    } else {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image_holder = jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).attr('class')+"-preview");
        image_holder.empty();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery(image_holder).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL((this).files[0]);
        jQuery('#image_preview').slideDown();
        jQuery(this).slideUp();
    }
});

/**
onclick event handler for the delete button.
It removes the image, clears and unhides the file input field.
*/
jQuery('#image_preview a').bind('click', function () {
    resetFormElement(jQuery('#image'));
    jQuery('#image').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).parent().slideUp();
    return false;
});

/** 
 * Reset form element
 * 
 * @param e jQuery object
 */
function resetFormElement(e) {
    e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    e.unwrap();
}
```

This is how the jQuery script is enqueued:

```
function the_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'images-preview', plugins_url( 'js/images_preview.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'images-preview', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_plugin_scripts' );
```

See a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9wrLzr92/2/) on JSFiddle.